# Why was Dr. Bashir a lieutenant instead of an ensign?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, starfleet-rank

In Deep Space 9, Dr. Bashir was posted to the space station as his first assignment, but he had the rank of Lieutenant Junior Grade. Why didn't he have a rank of Ensign? Was he fast-tracked?

Comment: I don't think he could have been Chief Medical Officer if he was only an ensign (of course, I may be wrong).

Comment: @Alexanderjones I guess this leads onto another question: Why was Dr Bashir made Chief Medical Officer when he has no experience?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Bashir (like his classmate [Elizabeth Lense](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Elizabeth_Lense)) was promoted to the rank of Lieutenant junior grade upon graduation from StarFleet in recognition for his medical training.**

This is the same as in real-world militaries today.

> When you join the Military, you will be commissioned as an officer. If you join during medical school, either through the  the Health Services Scholarship Program, the Uniformed Services University of the Health Sciences or the Medical and Dental Student Stipend Program, you will enter the Military as a second lieutenant in the Army and Air Force, or as an ensign in the Navy. **After graduation, you will advance to the rank of captain in the Army and Air Force, or lieutenant in the Navy.** If you join through the Financial Assistance Program, you will serve at the rank of at least captain (Army/Air Force), or lieutenant (Navy). - [Officer + Medical Training](http://medicineandthemilitary.com/officer-and-medical-training/military-officer-training)

This can also be true of enlisted individuals (such as in the [US Navy](http://usmilitary.about.com/od/navyjoin/a/advancedrate.htm)). Depending on your education level you may start at a higher rank upon competition of boot camp.

> - E-2 -- Authorized enlistment in, or advancement to, paygrade E2 having satisfactorily completed one academic year or 1080 classroom hours at an accredited vocational/technical school beyond high school level.
> - E-3 -- Authorized enlistment in, or advancement to, paygrade E3 having satisfactorily completed two academic years or 2160 classroom hours at an accredited vocational / technical school beyond high school level.

*These are two examples from the list, there are a number of things which allow an enlisted person to start at a higher rank and pay-grade, such as being an Eagle Scout, or attending a High School Miliary Academy.*

Comment: Much more elaborate answer than mine, sir. Myself, I was in the Navy, started at E-3, guaranteed E-4 with no test. Was fun times.

Comment: `enlisted men...`  I'm fairly sure there are enlisted _women_ as well...

Comment: @JaneS I changed it.

Comment: Although the requirement for enlisted ranking might be listed, in actuality all that is required is a signed contract. You can tell your recruiter you will not join at less than E-3 and he has the authority to sign that. All you have to do is know that's true and hold fast while he tries to whittle you down.

Answer (score 6):

Presumably in Starfleet, like real-world militaries, doctors are commissioned at a higher starting rank than other officers.  This is reflective of, among other things, the fact that physicians have to put in years of additional education after college, while regular officers (whether coming out of the military academy or an ROTC program) are typically commissioned right out of college.  Moreover, since doctors are, in the course of their professional duties, required to give orders to other people (who may, like military nurses, be officers themselves), it helps maintain military protocol to have the doctors start out at a rank well above O1, so they will typically outrank everyone who may be working under them.